# Dynamically split column based on a value in array

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV in which looks like this

```
|ID |tag|exists|
|---|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 --------|------|
|1  |[{"tag_uuid":"1a","tag_key":"tag1","tag_value":"value1 ","added_at":"2022-07-27T20:47:07.496Z"},{"tag_uuid":"1b","tag_key":"tag2","tag_value":"value2","added_at":"2022-07-27T20:47:07.480Z"}]|TRUE  |
|2  |[{"tag_uuid":"1a","tag_key":"tag1","tag_value":"value2","added_at":"2022-07-27T20:47:07.484Z"},{"tag_uuid":"1c","tag_key":"tag3","tag_value":"value1","added_at":"2022-07-27T20:47:07.409Z"}] |TRUE  |
|3  |[{"tag_uuid":"1c","tag_key":"tag3","tag_value":"value3","added_at":"2022-08-11T17:31:53.915Z"}]                                                                                               |TRUE  |
```

I want to dynamically split out the tag_key as a column and then add the tag_value for each individual row. If the column already exists, just add the value in the row. The amount of tag's can vary per row.

so it would ideally look like this...

| ID | exists? | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | value1 | value2 |  |
| 2 | TRUE | value2 |  | value1 |
| 3 | TRUE |  |  | value3 |

I just cant work it out in my head

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

#apply `ast.literal_eval` if values aren't converted already
df["tag"] = df["tag"].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode("tag")
df["tag_key"] = df["tag"].str["tag_key"]
df["tag_value"] = df["tag"].str["tag_value"]

df = (
    df.pivot(
        index=["ID", "exists"],
        columns="tag_key",
        values="tag_value",
    )
    .fillna("")
    .reset_index()
)
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  exists    tag1    tag2    tag3
0   1    True  value1  value2        
1   2    True  value2          value1
2   3    True                  value3
```