# How to manipulate the csv file in which values are in form of a list that has elements in type of strings which are in the form of list of dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file as follows

```
id,name,product
1234,Solar,"['id':'89521','status':'Active','productRatePlan':[{'id':'224416','name':'monthly charge', 'pricing': [{'currency':'USD','price': 109.13}]}]]"
```

I want the csv file like this

```
id,name,product.id,product.status,productRatePlan.id,productRatePlan.name,productRatePlan.currency,productRatePlan.price
1234,Solar,89521,Active,224416,monthly charge,USD,109.13
```

I am fetching the data via a http request, then when I open the file using csv.reader(filename), then it is coming in a form of a list that has elements in type of strings which are in the form of list of dictionary
I am facing trouble to access the values and make the value as the column name. The below code is that I have tried.

```
import csv

with open('newFile.csv') as nf:
    csvRead = csv.reader(nf)
    
    for row in csvRead:
        # if row == 'product':
        #     print(row)  
        print(row[2][2:4])
        print(type(row))
```

I know the approach I am doing is wrong, I have tried many combinations. It will be very helpful if someone guide me and tell me what are the resources I need in order to complete it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you creating the CSV, too?

Comment: This is not a list of dicts, nor is it a JSON array of objects. Where is this coming from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes Sir it is not a list of dicts, I am fetching the data via a http request, then when I open the file using csv.reader(filename), then it is coming in a form of a list that has elements in type of strings which are in the form of list of dictionary. Thank you

Comment: @ZachYoung either I can manipulate the existing csv or I can create the new one. Thank you

Comment: I was asking if you are consuming a file you created… did you put that data structure in the CSV in the first place? If so, I recommend not using CSV, use JSON. If you’re stuck with the CSV as it is, then literal_eval() from the ast will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73391634/246801